# Do extensions of pure states separate points?

Tags: c-star-algebras, amenability

Let $B$ be a unital C*-algebra  and let $A⊆B$ be a closed *-subalgebra containing the unit of $B$.  I am mostly
interested in the case that $A$ is abelian but, for the strict purpose of stating my question, this does not seem to
matter much.

Let us say that the inclusion "$A⊆B$" has property (EPS) (for *Extended Pure states Separate*)
provided the set of all  state extensions of pure states on $A$ separates points of $B$ in the sense that, if $b∈ B$, and
$\psi(b^*b)=0$, for all such states $\psi$, then $b=0$.

An example failing this property is $A=C([0,1])$ (represented on $L^2[0, 1]$ as multiplication
operators), and $B=A+K$ (compact operators), but I suspect the failure is due to the fact that $A$ is not a regular
subalgebra of $B$ (normalizers, in the sense of Kumjian, do not span $B$).  Nevertheless there are regular counter-examples as well.

For obvious reasons any inclusion of the form "$ℂ⊆B$" satisfies (EPS) and so does "$ℂ^n⊆B$".

Other situations in which (EPS) holds are:

- $B$ is abelian,
- $A$ is abelian, $B=A\rtimes G$, and $G$ is amenable.

My questions are:

**Questions**. Has property (EPS) been studied before?
Can it be characterized in some sensible way?

I suspect that this might have something to do with nuclearity,  so here is another:

**Question**.  If $A$ is abelian and regular and $B$  is nuclear,  can one show that (EPS) holds?

Comment: Is the paper " Extensions of Pure states and projections of norm one" by R. Archbold relevant?

Comment: Archbold's paper is definitely in the same ball park but I can't find any direct application of the results in that paper to my question, mainly  due to their strong hypotheses.  Nevertheless there are many ideas stemming from there which I'm going to try to pursue.  Thanks very much for suggesting it!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user @DarthVader I was led to consider a special case of my question, namely when every pure state of $A$ admits a unique extension to a state on $B$, and under this hypothesis I was able to answer my last question affirmatively: when $B$ is nuclear then the property (EPS) does hold.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.09445